# Read user input with spaces in csh Shell Script

Tags: shell, csh

I have a script where the user should be able to enter a string with spaces. So far I have:

```
#bin/csh

echo "TEST 1"
echo -n "Input : "
set TEST = $<

echo "Var | " $TEST

set TEST=`echo $TEST`

echo "Var after echo | " $TEST

set TEST=`echo $TEST | sed 's/ /_/g'`

echo "Var after change | " $TEST
```

If I enter the string "r r r" at "input", $TEST would only take "r". I want to be able to set $TEST to "r r r". Is this possible?
If I enter a string like "1 1 1" I get an error:

> set: Variable name must begin with a
>   letter.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Can I point you to http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ ? It won't solve your problem, but it illustrates various reasons why csh is not the best shell for programming :-)

Comment: Yes. I usually use sh. In this case, I need to navigate to a different directory and still be there when the script exists. I do this by using source (alias aenew 'source ~/scripts/aenewc'). So if the user is working in a c shell, the script would also have to be in "csh". That's the reason I've resorted to csh in this case.

Comment: Yes. I usually use sh. In this case, I need to navigate to a different directory and still be there when the script exists. I do this by using source (alias aenew 'source ~/scripts/aenewc'). So if the user is working in a c shell, the script would also have to be in "csh". That's the reason I've resorted to csh in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not using quotes in your `SET` statement. When you enter `"r r r"` as your input, the two different variants (unquoted and quoted) are equivalent to:

```
set TEST=$<    :is equivalent to:  set TEST=r r r
set TEST="$<"  :is equivalent to:  set TEST="r r r"
```

The first of those simply sets `TEST` to `"r"` and `r` to `""` (twice!). The second sets `TEST` to `"r r r"`. That's because `csh` lets you do multiple assignments like:

```
set a=1 b=2 c d=4
```

So you need to use the quoted variant of `SET`. Examine the following transcript to see how it works:

```
[pax ~]$ set x=$< ; echo .$x.
hello
.hello.

[pax ~]$ set x="$<" ; echo $x ; echo .$b.$c.
a b c
.a b c.
b: Undefined variable.

[pax ~]$ set x=$< ; echo $x ; echo .$b.$c.
a b c
.a.
...

[pax ~]$ set x=$< ; echo $x ; echo .$b.$c.
a b=7 c=urk!
.a.
.7.urk!.
```

The reason you're getting the error you describe with input of `"1 1 1"` is because you're effectively executing:

```
set TEST=1 1 1
```

and `csh` is taking this to mean that you want to create the variable `TEST` set to `"1"` followed by the variable `1`, which doesn't start with a letter, hence not allowed. With the quoted variant, this becomes:

```
set TEST="1 1 1"
```

which will do what you expect.